# How do you completely run an if statement before moving to the next one?

Tags: java

This question is very hard to put into concise wording. How would I modify my code to meet the constraints I'm given in this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int [][] test = { {1, 6, 11, 16, 21}, 
                            {2, 7, 12, 17, 22}, 
                            {3, 8, 13, 18, 23}, 
                            {4, 9, 14, 19, 24}, 
                            {5, 10, 15, 20, 25} };
    System.out.println(TwoDOneD.XShape(test));

public static String XShape(int [][] test) {
    String res = "";
    for (int c = 0; c < test[0].length; c++) {
         for (int r = 0; r < test.length; r++) {
            if (c == r) {
                res += test[r][c] + " ";
            } else if (c + r == 4) {
                res += test[r][c] + " ";
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

The point of this code is to put the integers that make an X pattern into a string and to print the string. This is the output I get whenever I run it:

```
1 5 7 9 13 17 19 21 25
```

But I want the output to look like this (using the first if statement first, adding all of those values into the string, then moving to the other else if statement and adding all of those values into the string):

```
1 7 13 19 25 21 17 13 9 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need an extra loop if you use 2 results, then join them at the end:

```
String res1, res2 = "";
for (int c = 0; c < test[0].length; c++) {
     for (int r = 0; r < test.length; r++) {
        if (c == r) {
            res1 += test[r][c] + " ";
        } else if (c + r == 4) {
            res2 += test[r][c] + " ";
        }
    }
}
return res1 + res2;
```

Comment: I feel legally obligated to be incredibly pedantic and remind you that there are two loops in your code. But I see the point you're making and agree with it.

Comment: @silvio it’s OK to be pedantic - this is a safe place - and you’re quite right too. I’ve improved the accuracy of my text, and it feels better too.

Answer (score 1):

You need two loops.

One where `c = r` and another where `c = 4 - r`

You don't need to use nested loops, just one each. You also don't need an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have two nested for loops. They're going to run and iterate in column-major order. If you want to iterate in a different order, then you need to use different loops. There's nothing wrong with the if statement.

```
for (int c = 0; c < test.length; c++) {
  // Do it for (c, c)
}
for (int c = 0; c < test.length; c++) {
  // Do it for (c, test.length - c - 1)
}
```

Also, as a tangential note, you use `4` as a magic number in one place and `test.length` in others. If you always expect the array to be 5x5, then use `5` instead of `test.length` and put an assertion at the beginning. Otherwise (more likely), use `test.length - 1` in place of the magic number `4`.